# Mapping over array using Async/Await with Puppeteer to return result

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, puppeteer

I'm new to working with async programming, so there may be something simple I'm missing out on here.

I have an express project, I'm passing an array in the body of my request.

Inside my function, I validate the body then parse the array and use a promise as I map over the array.

```
const games = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body.games));

const gamesMap = games.map((game) => gameSearch(game));

return Promise.all(gamesMap)
    .then(function(g) {
        // async is still running here, I want to wait until it returns 
        console.log(g); // returns [ undefined, undefined, ... ]
    });
```

The game search function uses `puppeteer` to use a headless browser to return prices of the game passed in array. However, it doesn't wait until the array is returned before `Promise.all` is called, so the `console.log(g);` above returns an undefined array. I assume it is something to do with using async await inside the `gameSearch` function, although I'm not sure what I am supposed to do here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function gameSearch(game) {
  (async () => {
    const url = '.....' + game;
    try {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36');
      await page.goto(url);
      const selector = '.searchRcrd';
      await page.waitForSelector(selector);

      const searchRcrds = await page.$$(selector);

      const records = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < searchRcrds.length; i++) {
        const searchRcrd = searchRcrds[i];
        const title = await searchRcrd.$eval('h1', (h1) => h1.innerText.trim());
        const buyFor = await searchRcrd.$eval('.desc .prodPrice div:nth-child(2) .priceTxt:nth-child(1)', (buy) => buy.innerText.trim());
        const inStoreFor = await searchRcrd.$eval('.desc .priceTxt:nth-child(2)', (inStore) => inStore.innerText.trim());
        const imgSrc = await searchRcrd.$eval('div.thumb > a > img', (img) => img.src.trim());

        records.push({
          'title': title,
          'buyFor': buyFor,
          'inStoreFor': inStoreFor,
          'imgSrc': imgSrc
        });
      }

      await browser.close();

      return records;
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  })();
}
```

Comment: Why does your `gameSearch` function not `return` anything? What good is the IIFE inside it? And why does it still use the callback approach for errors (`next(err)`)?

Comment: @Bergi It should return `records`. I was just following a tutorial online, this was how they approached this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return records` returns from the `(async () => {…})();` IIFE. Drop that and make `gameSearch` itself an `async function` that returns (a promise for) the array.

```
async function gameSearch(game) {
  const url = '.....' + game;
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36');
  await page.goto(url);
  const selector = '.searchRcrd';
  await page.waitForSelector(selector);

  const searchRcrds = await page.$$(selector);

  const records = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < searchRcrds.length; i++) {
    const searchRcrd = searchRcrds[i];
    const title = await searchRcrd.$eval('h1', (h1) => h1.innerText.trim());
    const buyFor = await searchRcrd.$eval('.desc .prodPrice div:nth-child(2) .priceTxt:nth-child(1)', (buy) => buy.innerText.trim());
    const inStoreFor = await searchRcrd.$eval('.desc .priceTxt:nth-child(2)', (inStore) => inStore.innerText.trim());
    const imgSrc = await searchRcrd.$eval('div.thumb > a > img', (img) => img.src.trim());

    records.push({
      'title': title,
      'buyFor': buyFor,
      'inStoreFor': inStoreFor,
      'imgSrc': imgSrc
    });
  }

  await browser.close();

  return records;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, I knew it would be something simple.